# How to force valid properties & values to be set on all files being added/updated in SVN?

Tags: python, svn, properties, pre-commit-hook

Is it possible to force a user who is either committing a change or adding a new file to set valid values for svn:keywords (e.g. Date, Author, & URL)?

It would be great if this behavior could be included in a pre-commit hook, preferably written in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:
http://mr-ats.tigris.org/svn/mr-ats/trunk/src/hooks/property-check/

login is: guest /[no password]